# Associate array of returns of commands

Tags: shell-escape

I'm trying to get strings from an external program, as shown in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{xunicode}
  \newcounter{verse}
  \stepcounter{verse}
  \immediate\write18{/home/rpinson/bas/tex/diatheke2tex "Jn 3:16" "FreMartin" "\roman{verse}" "\jobname.verses"}
  \begin{document}
  \input{\jobname.verses}
  \versei
\end{document}
```

Where `diatheke2tex` is:

```
#!/bin/bash

REF="$1"
VERSION="$2"
ID="$3"
FILE="$4"

echo "\\newcommand\\verse${ID}{%" >> $FILE

diatheke -o plain -b "$VERSION" -k "$REF" | \
  head -n -1 | \
  sed -e 's/^[^:]\+ [0-9:]\+://' >> $FILE

echo "}" >> $FILE
```

The `\versei` is kind of a hack, as it's not possible to use spaces and numbers in a macro name. Obviously, this is not a proper solution…

How can I build an associative array of some sort associating references (like `Jn 3:16`) to the result of the command (in this case `Car Dieu a tant aimé le monde, qu'il a donné son Fils unique, afin que quiconque croit en lui ne périsse point, mais qu'il ait la vie éternelle.`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, spaces and numbers can be used in a macro name (csname),
see an example of definition and usage of an associating reference below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\expandafter\def\csname[Jn 3:16]\endcsname{Car Dieu a tant aimé le monde\dots}
\begin{document}
\csname[Jn 3:16]\endcsname
\end{document}
```